# why i have to pass parameter as a querystring to Action Method in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm new to `mvc`. I'm creating a test application in `mvc`.

[here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-controller) I've studied that `mvc` works with url as `/[Controller]/[ActionName]/[Parameters]`

But in my application i have to pass parameter as `/home/index?name=test`. I think it should work as `/home/index/test`. But it doesn't work in this way.

**Here is `ActionMethod` in `homeController`**

```
 public ActionResult Index(String name)
    {
        ViewBag.name = name;
        return View();
    }
```

**Routing code in `Global.asax.cs`**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

 }

  <h2>@ViewBag.name</h2>
```

Can anyone help me to findout that why its not working in `/home/index/test` format.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Is the Index action being invoked but the parameter not set?

Comment: its not giving any error. Just showing me a blank page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Routes.MapRoute(
        "DefaultWithName", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{name}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Because your optional parameter says "id", and in your controller it's "name".

Comment: @CodeRider this is the correct answer. make sure that you haven't other errors

Answer (score 2):

As Lars points out, your route specifies the default parameter name as ID. Your controller specifies it as "name."  If you changed your controller parameter to say, int ID,  then home/index/3 would work.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by @Lars & @Joel, your route specifies the default parameter name as ID.

Declare

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "DefaultWithName", // Route name
           "{controller}/{action}/{name}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

And to use route use code

```
@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultWithName", new { name = "test" })
```

Instead of `@Url.Action`